# How to define variable types while loading dataset using column names rather than column index?

Tags: stata

When I need to load a dataset where some specific columns must be read as string I type:

```
import delimited "data.csv", stringcols(13 15 16)
```

Where 13, 15 and 16 are the number of columns in my dataset that I want to read as string. However, I usually don't know the columns' numbers beforehand and it would be nice to be able to do the same thing using the columns' names.

I tried:

```
import delimited "data.csv", stringcols(var1 var2 var3)
```

But `stringcols` doesn't accept non-numeric arguments. Is there a way to specify columns types using the columns' names rather than numbers?

In python I can do this using:

```py
df=pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype={k:str for k in ["var1", 'var2', 'var3']})
```

I'm looking for a similar method in Stata.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be such an option. The main aim of `import delimited` is to be smart on your behalf, with scope for fixing mistakes afterwards with `destring` or `tostring`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually encounter this problem a lot. As Nick said, the current version of `import delimited` does not support variable names.

A workaround is to import all columns as strings by specifying the `stringcols(_all)` option and then manually convert those variables of interest.

For example,

```
import delimited data.csv, stringcols(_all) clear
destring var4 var5 var6, replace
```

If you have a very long list of variables and want to `destring` all variables apart from say `var1 var2 var3`, you can use the `ds` command (thanks to Nick for the suggestion):

```
import delimited data.csv, stringcols(_all) clear
ds var1 var2 var3, not //specify a list of variables to be excluded 
destring `r(varlist)', replace
```

If you are working with a very large number of unstructured Excel files, you may find the [excelclean](https://github.com/hanlulong/excelclean) command useful.